# Generic types and ienumerable<T>, where to start

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass in a dataset to a function but it could be different each time (but will always implement IEnumerable. So my call to the function will be:

```
var items = new List<AssetListItem>();
AimsFunctions.dropdown("Asset", "id", items)
```

or

```
var items = new List<AssetCategory>();
AimsFunctions.dropdown("Cats", "id", items)
```

But how do I work with this in the function?

```
public static SelectBox dropdown(string name, string key IEnumerable<T> dataset )
    {
       // Want to work with dataset with Linq here
    }
```

says it doesnt understand what T is in IEnumerable (although neither do i :)

Comment: Why not a List of object and you cast your object as you like 
Somthing like 
`var items = new List<Object>();`

Comment: I've given an answer for your *immediate* problem, but as we don't know what you're trying to do in the method body, you may well find it only gets you one step nearer... you may well need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `T` as a type argument, so the compiler needs to know which `T` you mean. Chances are you want to make your method a generic method too. Fixing the name to follow conventions (and be more readable in general) at the same time, you'd have:

```
public static SelectBox CreateDropdown<T>(string name, string key, IEnumerable<T> rows)
{
    ...
}
```

The `<T>` part after the method name is what indicates that it's a generic method. If you're new to generics, you should probably read the [MS guide to generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs `<T>` to be generic. You could use reflection although i don't like using it:

```
public static DropDownList Dropdown<T>(string name, string key, IEnumerable<T> dataset) where T: class 
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(p => p.CanRead && (p.Name == name || p.Name == key))
        .ToArray();
    if (properties.Length < 2) throw new ArgumentException("The name and the key properties must exist and the they have to be public");

    var nameprop = properties.First(p => p.Name == name);
    var keyprop = properties.First(p => p.Name == key);

    var data = dataset
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Name = nameprop.GetValue(x, null)?.ToString(),
            Key = keyprop.GetValue(x, null)?.ToString(),
        })
        .ToList();

    // use this as datasource for your SelectBox/DropDownList
}
```